# missing first row after resample

Tags: pandas

I have a problem with pandas dropping 1st row when I am resampling certain data. Please see the example below. Note that if you advance the last timestamp forward by 1 second it works as expected.

I am using pandas 0.10.1

```
import pandas as pd

from datetime import datetime
from StringIO import StringIO


f = StringIO('''\
time,value
2011-06-03 00:00:05,0
2011-06-03 00:01:05,1
2011-06-03 00:02:05,2
''')

series = pd.read_csv(f, parse_dates=True, index_col=0)['value']

print series
# time
# 2011-06-03 00:00:05    0
# 2011-06-03 00:01:05    1
# 2011-06-03 00:02:05    2
# Name: value

# Problem resampling: 1st sample is missing

print series.resample('s')
# time
# 2011-06-03 00:00:06   NaN
# 2011-06-03 00:00:07   NaN
# 2011-06-03 00:00:08   NaN
# 2011-06-03 00:00:09   NaN
# ...
# 2011-06-03 00:01:52   NaN
# 2011-06-03 00:02:03   NaN
# 2011-06-03 00:02:04   NaN
# 2011-06-03 00:02:05     2
# 2011-06-03 00:02:06   NaN
# Freq: S, Name: value, Length: 121
```

Comment: When I run this code, the first line of the output is ``2011-06-03 00:00:05     0`` -- i.e., the first sample is not missing. Maybe this is an issue with an early version of pandas (although I have not heard of it). Could you tell us the version? ``pd.__version__``

Comment: Thanks @DanAllan, I'm using 0.10.1, looks like it is fixed in 0.12.

Answer (score 0):

The default for the closed parm was changed in 0.11, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/2410). I don't know if there was a bug there as well. You can try to specifiy the closed interval.

Current pandas version is 0.12 (0.13 coming soon). best bet is to upgrade.

from 0.12. Looks ok. Default is closed='left'

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
                     value
time                      
2011-06-03 00:00:05      0
2011-06-03 00:01:05      1
2011-06-03 00:02:05      2

In [12]: df.index
Out[12]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2011-06-03 00:00:05, ..., 2011-06-03 00:02:05]
Length: 3, Freq: None, Timezone: None

In [13]: df.resample('1s')
Out[13]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 121 entries, 2011-06-03 00:00:05 to 2011-06-03 00:02:05
Freq: S
Data columns (total 1 columns):
value    3  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1)

In [14]: df.resample('1s').head()
Out[14]: 
                     value
time                      
2011-06-03 00:00:05      0
2011-06-03 00:00:06    NaN
2011-06-03 00:00:07    NaN
2011-06-03 00:00:08    NaN
2011-06-03 00:00:09    NaN
```